# Scrollbar for questions in profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

For some reason I currently get a scrollbar for the questions list on my profile. It doesn't do anything useful as the list is still paged as usual. This also only happens on my gaming.SE profile, not on any other SE site.

Screenshot:

[image]